# Find number of instances of a letter, and specific string combinations, in a matrix with randomly repeated strings

Tags: matlab, matrix, counting

In a matrix consisting of random repetitions of the letter triplets ABC DEF GHI and JKL, how do I count how many times A occurred in the 4*60 matrix?[image]
The next question is how many times a combination occurred. As is visible, ABC followed by (for example) GHI has a unique C-G combination occurring. How to test how many times such combinations occur throughout the 4*60 matrix.

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu5K5.png)

So, this is what my code looks like so far. The only bit I'm stuck with is, this:
so in the matrix, ABC can be followed by DEF, GHI or JKL. I want to how many times it is followed by, say, DEF. I'll need to code that individually for all possible combinations but if I get the code to begin with, I can work from there.

Comment: Please post your code as editable text and not as an image. Nobody wants to transcribe the code from image to textual description.

Answer (score 0):

Creating matrix, randomly containing 'ABC', 'DEF','GHI','JKL'

```
str = {'ABC', 'DEF','GHI','JKL'};
M = cell(4,60);
for j = 1:size(M,2)
    rands = randperm(4);
    for i = 1:size(M,1)
        M{i,j} = str{rands(i)};
    end
end
```

Answer to first question, "How to find the number of instances of 'A' ":

```
nbrOfA = length(find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(M,'A'))));
```

Or if you would like to find all instances of all letters:

```
alph = strcat(str{1},str{2},str{3},str{4});
for i = 1:length(alph)
   eval([alph(i),' = length(find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(M,alph(i)))))'])
end
```

Answer to second question, "How many times a combination occurred":

```
% Define which combos you look for, e.g. 'ABC' and GHI in this case
e1 = str{1};
e2 = str{3};

% Find index in M where e1 is found 
idxe1 = find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(M,e1)));

% Find index in M where e2 is found
idxe2 = find(~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(M,e2)));

% Find where the combination occurs
matches = find(ismember(idxe1,idxe2-1) == 1);

% Answer to the question "How many times a combination occurred"
nbrOfComb = length(matches);
```

And in case you would like the indices in M, for 'ABC' and 'GHI' which gave rise to the combination:

```
idxe1Matches = idxe1(matches);
idxe2Matches = idxe1(matches)+1;
```

i.e., for verification, if you write `[M(idxe1Matches), M(idxe2Matches)]` you should get:

```
>> [M(idxe1Matches), M(idxe2Matches)]

ans = 

    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
    'ABC'    'GHI'
```

Comment: What do you say @Insane Skull? Did I understand the question correctly?

Comment: Hi @JCKaz. I already coded the random matrix production of triplets of letters. Although your code does the job, I want no repetitions of a triplet, which your code does unfortunately.  

%// Elements to be contained, but no zero allowed
a = [1 2 3 4];
%// all possible permutations and its size
n = length(a);
N=60;
%// initialization
output = zeros(4,N);
output(:,1)=randperm(4).';
 
for i=2:N
 
b=randperm(4);
b=b';
if output(4,i-1)==b(1)
      b([1 2])=b([2 1]);
end
if (b(1)==output(3,i-1) & b(2)==output(4,i-1))
b([1 2 3 4])=b([3 4 1 2]);
end
output(:,i)=b;
end

Comment: %// Elements to be contained, but no zero allowed
a = [1 2 3 4];
%// all possible permutations and its size
n = length(a);
N=60;
%// initialization
output = zeros(4,N);
output(:,1)=randperm(4).';
 
for i=2:N
 
b=randperm(4);
b=b';
if output(4,i-1)==b(1)
      b([1 2])=b([2 1]);
end
if (b(1)==output(3,i-1) & b(2)==output(4,i-1))
b([1 2 3 4])=b([3 4 1 2]);
end
output(:,i)=b;
end

mq= {'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'};
mq(output)

This code gives both the digits and the letter triplets randomly distributed in the matrix.

Comment: could you tell me how to find the number of times each letter occurs in the matrix for my code? Yours doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Save a variable `M = mq(output);` and my code will work. However, if you do not have any repetition of triplets, you are guaranteed to have exactly 60 instances of all letters.

Comment: I have updated my answer now. Also, I created the matrix (without repetitions in the columns) in 8 lines, if it's of interest.

Comment: The only bit I'm stuck with is, this: so in the matrix, ABC can be followed by DEF, GHI or JKL. I want to how many times it is followed by, say, DEF. I'll need to code that individually for all possible combinations but if I get the code to begin with, I can work from there.  
to make it sound easier, take 1 = ABC, 2=DEF, 3=GHI, 4=JKL. In a 4*60 matrix of random distributions of these, I'd like to know how many times was 1 followed by 2. I can code it further to check for combinations with 3 and 4 and so forth. Because, my matrix, in digits, looks like this: 
1 2 3 4
2 3 2 3 
3 4 1 1 
4 1 4 2

Comment: You pretty much get this from `nbrOfComb` in my code. Under my headline "Answer to second question, 'How many times a combination occurred':" you have everything you need to find how many times any given combination occurs. You can just change the variables `e1` and `e2` to look at other combinations.